# Extjs Tree nodes with three state icons on nodes

Tags: extjs, tree

How to add a new icon before the checkbox (parallely) of each node to Extjs tree built from Json data, that has checkbox in the tree nodes? How to find the events on those icon and checkbox?

I googled a lot for such icons (seems it uses `elbow` CSS class internally).

You may see the uploaded image at: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/v1s5.png/

Comment: Perhaps if you provide an image of your desired result it would help us to understand what you're asking for here.

Comment: kindly see the image link added in question..

Comment: Let me know if some one has any solution...